# How to configure the default Jackson JSON Mapper on Javalin

Tags: json, kotlin, javalin, ktorm

So far, i found how to replace Javalin json mapper:

https://javalin.io/documentation#configuring-the-json-mapper

But i don't want to replace it, just want to add a few jackson modules, like this one:

https://www.ktorm.org/api-docs/org.ktorm.jackson/-ktorm-module/index.html

Without this, Javalin fails to serialize ktorm entities, sample code [here](https://github.com/sombriks/rosetta-beer-store/blob/master/beer-store-service-kotlin-javalin-ktorm-liquibase/src/main/kotlin/beer/store/controllers/MediaContoller.kt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

In JavalinConfig you can set an implementation of [JsonMapper](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/0577406d7605e351efb8e47eef7aabaf0308e3ad/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/plugin/json/JsonMapper.kt)

The [default implementation](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/0577406d7605e351efb8e47eef7aabaf0308e3ad/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/plugin/json/JavalinJackson.kt) accepts an [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.14/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java) as parameter, so i can do this:

```
// custom config to make ktor and jackson behave
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule.Builder().build())
mapper.registerModule(KtormModule())

// spin up app
val app = Javalin.create {
    it.jsonMapper(JavalinJackson(mapper))
}.start(3000)
```

And then Javalin and Ktorm works perfectly together.

UPDATE:

[Now Javalin will detect KtormModule for you!](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/commit/9af9a8f43771e5194cae0337443ac16a9c4eeb16)

Answer (score 2):

You can update the default Jackson mapper by doing:

```
val app = Javalin.create {
    config.jsonMapper(JavalinJackson().updateMapper { mapper ->
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    })
}.start(3000)
```

See more at https://javalin.io/documentation#the-default-json-mapper-jackson